# How to implement a bubble sort that only performs "K" times

Tags: python, algorithm

I am solving the following bubble sort algorithm.

However, this algorithm does not seem to be a common bubble sort implementation. I have implemented the following code, but it will time out. The reason is that the time complexity of my code is still O (n^2).

How do I write code for a bubble sort to correctly understand and solve the problem?

**Solution**

> Bubble sorting is an algorithm that sorts sequences of length N in such a way that two adjacent elements are examined to change their positions. Bubble sorting can be performed N times as shown below.
>
> 1. Compare the first value with the second value, and change the position if the first value is greater.
> 2. Compares the second value with the third value, and changes the position if the second value is greater.
>
> ...
>
> 3. Compare the N-1 and N-th values, and change the position if the N-1th value is greater.
>    I know the result of bubble sorting, so I know the intermediate process of bubble sorting. However, since N is very large, it takes a long time to perform the above steps K times. Write a program that will help you to find the intermediate process of bubble sorting.

**Input**

> N and K are given in the first line.
>
> The second line gives the status of the first sequence. That is, N integers forming the first sequence are given in turn, with spaces between them.
>
> 1 <= N <= 100,000
> 1 <= K <= N
> Each term in the sequence is an integer from 1 to 1,000,000,000.

**Output**

> The above steps are repeated K times and the status of the sequence is output.

**Commandline**

```
Example input
4 1
62 23 32 15
Example output
23 32 15 62
```

**My Code**

```
n_k = input()  # 4 1
n_k_s = [int(num) for num in n_k.split()]

progression = input()  # 62 23 32 15 => 23 32 15 62
progressions = [int(num) for num in progression.split()]


def bubble(n_k_s, progressions):
    for i in range(0, n_k_s[1]):
        for j in range(i, n_k_s[0]-1):
            if (progressions[j] > progressions[j+1]):
                temp = progressions[j]
                progressions[j] = progressions[j+1]
                progressions[j+1] = temp
    for k in progressions:
        print(k, end=" ")


bubble(n_k_s, progressions)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confused as to why you're saying "The reason is that the time complexity of my code is still O (n^2)"

The time complexity is always O(n²), unless you add a flag to check if your list is already sorted (complexity would now be 0(n) if the list is sorted at the beginning of your program)

Comment: When type "4 and 1" as in the example input, the list is sorted once. In this case, I think it is O(n). However, when the value is "4 and 2" or more, the time complexity of O(n^2) is required.

If so, can I maintain an O(n) if I create and return an ordered list each time I perform sorting? Is this the problem want?

Comment: When you set K to 1, your time complexity is indeed O(n)
When you set K to 2, your time complexity becomes O(n * 2)
As such, the time complexity of your algorithm is O(n * K).

If you create a new list each time, the complexity of your algorithm won't change, because you still would have gone through your list K times

Comment: This problem will cause a timeout error if the time complexity exceeds O (n ^ 2).
So I think the problem is that you do not want to implement simple bubble sorting. What do you think about this?

Comment: In your answer, I think I got a hint.

Comment: @COLEAN (Sorry about the late answer)
If you want to use a bubble sort with a complexity lower than O(n^2), you need to implement exit conditions into it.
IE: You can add a flag that checks, whenever you loop, if you've actually swapped elements. If you haven't, this means your list is already sorted.
EG: 15 32 23 62 with K = 5
=> First time you sort, you'll end up with 15 23 32 62 (32 swaps with 23)
=> Second time you sort, you won't have to swap anything because the list is already sorted, so you should be exiting your code
=> Time complexity becomes O(n * 2), would have been O(n * 5).

Answer (score 1):

As best I can tell, you have implemented the algorithm requested.  It is **O(nk)**; `Phillippe` already covered the rationale I was typing.

Yes, you can set a flag to indicate whether you've made any exchanges on this pass.  That doesn't change any complexity except for best-case -- although it does reduce the constant factor in many other cases.

One possibility I see for speeding up your process is to use a more efficient value exchange: use the Python idiom `a, b = b, a`.  In your case, the inner loop might become:

```
done = True
for j in range(i, n_k_s[0]-1):
    if progressions[j] > progressions[j+1]:
        progressions[j], progressions[j+1] = progressions[j+1], progressions[j]
        done = False
if done:
    break
```

Comment: If done = False in the packing process, when is done: True?

Comment: If no switches are made during the pass, that means that the list is sorted.  `done` retains its `True` value from before the loop.  I moved it to its correct position.